# Magento: Can I mark an order as shipped and send the tracking number in the same API call?

Tags: api, magento, tracking

Using the Magento API, I see how to mark an order as shipped with the sales_order_shipment.create call and how to add a tracking number with the sales_order_shipment.addTrack call.  Is there a way to send the tracking number as part of the sales_order_shipment.create call to save a another request?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no there is not in the default API. You could modify the API to create your own call, however, and add this functionality.

Or, save us all and make a modification to contribute back upstream to Magento core :)

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Wow. That has been 2 years and still no such API :P